# How do you execute the PHP component of a page that is being built out of Radiant CMS?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, radiant

I have a script on a page that has a PHP component.  My entire site is being managed using RadiantCMS. Currently, the PHP is turned off on my web hosting because I've been told PHP and Rails do not play well together.  So currently, the script will not run since the PHP component is not executing.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed or wrap my mind around this.  It's only 1 page that needs to execute the PHP script so that the main javascript will run but the problem is getting PHP to run alongside Rails and I'm not sure how it affects all my other website pages that are currently based out of Radiant.

Is this just not feasible to implement?  Otherwise, I don't know what to expect if my webhosting turns on the PHP.  Should I just assume then that's all it would take for the PHP to run while I'm deploying the entire site through Radiant?

I looked at a couple of threads on PHP running alongside Rails but don't know how to make this applicable to my situation. Sorry, I'm not a developer and I do not know too much about the back-end.

I'm still waiting to hear back from the developer of the script I want to use before I contact my web hosting provider. In the meantime, any advice or possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the less than humble people out there downvoting this who apparently know everything there is in the universe.  Imagine what the world would be like if people who didn't know things stopped asking questions in order to solve their problems.  Imagine if you had children and sent them to school and those kids had their peers downgrade their questions so they stopped asking questions to fill their knowledge gaps and they come out of school a DRONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually "turning on" a additional programming or scripting language like PHP or Ruby do not interfere each other. 
If you use RadiantCMS and therefore Ruby to generate the contents of your sites you may get in trouble with integrating a PHP program into this environment.

Telling the provider switching on PHP should not cause any trouble with your active installation at all. And there should be a way to execute the PHP somehow - with the correct webserver settings - and get the script running. Just give it a try.

Anyway, if you are not familiar with programming you should have some helping hands. Because what you do when you upload a script to your server is problematic; Everyone can execute it by asking the webserver to do it. This may be an security issue. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the clarification.  Now that I know it is feasible, I can ask the support desk at my webhosting provider to assist with the implementation.

Comment: Yeah, thats great. Best luck with it!